# How to prevent child QGraphicsItem from being moved with parent?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have a `GraphicsBoxItem` that holds a list of `GraphicsImageItem` (some kind of floating buttons around the box). I create them on the fly in `focusInEvent()` and destroy them in `focusOutEvent()`. 
Some of the `GraphicsImageItem` should move with the parent when clicked, some of them should stay at the same spot when clicked, until the box gets a focusOut by clicking outside of any graphics items.
Is there a way to prevent a child QGraphicsItem from being moved with the parent?

```
class GraphicsBoxItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QColor mColor;
    QVector<GraphicsImageItem*> mItemList;
public:
    GraphicsBoxItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = NULL)
        :QGraphicsItem(parent)
    {
        mColor = Qt::lightGray;
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const { return QRectF(50, 20, 100, 60); }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
        painter->setBrush(mColor);
        painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
    }
    virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent * event)
    {
        foreach(GraphicsImageItem *item1, mItemList)
        {
            item1->deleteLater();
            item1 = NULL;
        }
        mItemList.clear();
        mColor = Qt::lightGray;
        QGraphicsItem::focusOutEvent(event);
    }

    virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent * event)
    {
        GraphicsImageItem *movableItem = new GraphicsImageItem(this);
        movableItem->setPos(150, 20);
        mItemList.push_back(movableItem);
        movableItem->installSceneEventFilter(this);
        connect(movableItem, SIGNAL(SignalClicked()), this, SLOT(SlotButtonClicked()));

        GraphicsImageItem *nonMovableItem = new GraphicsImageItem(this);
        nonMovableItem->setPos(20, 20);
        mItemList.push_back(nonMovableItem);
        nonMovableItem->installSceneEventFilter(this);
        connect(nonMovableItem, SIGNAL(SignalClicked()), this, SLOT(SlotButtonClicked()));

        mColor = Qt::blue;
        QGraphicsItem::focusInEvent(event);
    }

    bool sceneEventFilter(QGraphicsItem* target, QEvent* event)
    {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress || event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick)
        {
            GraphicsImageItem* item = dynamic_cast<GraphicsImageItem*>(target);
            if(item)
            {
                item->SignalClicked();
                qDebug() << "image button was clicked: Need to set the focus back to the box";
                setFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return QGraphicsItem::sceneEventFilter(target, event);
    }
public slots:

    void SlotButtonClicked()
    {
        setPos(pos().x() + 10, pos().y()+10);
    }
};
```

`SignalClicked()` moves the `GraphicsBoxItem` by 10 pixels. Some of the `GraphicsImageItem` stay put, some move with `GraphicsBoxItem`:

```
class GraphicsImageItem : public QGraphicsSvgItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GraphicsImageItem::GraphicsImageItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = NULL)
    : QGraphicsSvgItem(QString(":/images/icon.svg"), parent)
    {
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const { return QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30); }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
        painter->setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
        painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
        renderer()->render(painter, boundingRect().adjusted(3, 3, -3, -3));
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void SignalClicked();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

A child's position is always relative to its parent, if the parent moves, then the child's absolute position changes too.

If you want to create the illusion that this doesn't happen, you will have to manually move the child in the opposite direction, so it can remain in the same absolute position.

The other option would be to not have the items as children in the first place.

Maybe you should create an invisible item, then parent the movable item as well as the non-movable children to it, and the movable children - under the movable item. Then you simply only move the movable item - its children move, its siblings stay in the same position, as their parent doesn't move.

Comment: I tried the approach with using a different parent for the movable items. This approach didn't work though, because I re-create all items in `focusIn()`. Inside that function I can't know if I got there because of a click on the button (button should stay at same position) or because I clicked outside of any items. After the next click on box, I would need to position the non-movable button right next to the box.  Is there a way to prevent the box from getting a focusOut() event when the `GraphicsImageItem` button is pressed?

Comment: @user2246120 `Inside that function I can't know` yes you can, simply pass a parameter to indicate the origin.

Comment: I meant `focusInEvent(QFocusEvent*)` coming from Qt. Initially, the non-movable item is on the top left corner of the box when the box gets focus. Then the item stays while the box moves. when pressing outside of the scene, and selecting the box again, the non-movable item should now be placed next to the box again. Not losing focus on the box while clicking the non-movable item would solve the problem... Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

For the child items you don't want to move, try set this flag:

```
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in this case. The documentation says: "its position is still anchored to its parent"...

Answer (score 0):

If you can subclass your child items, then you can override the itemChange() method and watch for:

ItemScenePositionHasChanged

> The item's scene position has changed. This notification is sent if
>   the ItemSendsScenePositionChanges flag is enabled, and after the
>   item's scene position has changed (i.e., the position or
>   transformation of the item itself or the position or transformation of
>   any ancestor has changed). The value argument is the new scene
>   position (the same as scenePos()), and QGraphicsItem ignores the
>   return value for this notification (i.e., a read-only notification).

Then then return the child item's last scenePos() which you'll have to store as a member and update each scene position change.

Remember to set the flag:

ItemSendsGeometryChanges

in your child subclass's ctor.